# the value of type '' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type ''

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have attached property `InteractionService.Triggers`, which is of type `TriggersCollection`, which derives from `List<ITrigger>`. So I put in XAML some trigger objects, and each one of them implements interface `ITrigger`. It works fine and was builded without any errors. But when I ported this library from Silverlight 5 to Windows Phone 8 and try to use it with scenario described above, Visual Studio 2012 underlined this XAML with blue line and tells that there is an such error. When I compile project, error dissapear from XAML in VS2012 until next edits in this XAML file.
How can I resolve this issue? Or this is a bug of VS2012 with WP8 SDK? Is there any workaround for this case?

Fragment of XAML (underlined by VS2012+WP8SDK, but not by VS2010+SL5):

```
<deToolkit:InteractionService.Triggers>
   <deToolkit:EventTrigger EnterEvent="Loaded">
       <deToolkit:CommandSetter Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" />
   </deToolkit:EventTrigger>
</deToolkit:InteractionService.Triggers>
```

TriggersCollection:

```
public class TriggersCollection : List<ITrigger> { }
```

Header of EventTrigger class:

```
public class EventTrigger : TriggerBase
```

Header of TriggerBase class:

```
public class TriggerBase : DependencyObject, ITrigger
```

Fragment of class InteractionService:

```
public sealed class InteractionService : DependencyObject
{
    #region [ADP] Triggers : TriggersCollection (Triggers applied to control)

    public static void SetTriggers(DependencyObject element, TriggersCollection value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TriggersProperty, value);
    }

    public static TriggersCollection GetTriggers(DependencyObject element)
    {
        var triggers = (TriggersCollection)element.GetValue(TriggersProperty);
        if (triggers == null)
        {
            var collection = new TriggersCollection();

            if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
            {
                // -- some code --
            }

            SetTriggers(element, collection);
            return collection;
        }
        return triggers;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Triggers", typeof(TriggersCollection), typeof(InteractionService), null);

    #endregion Triggers
}
```

Error:

> A value of type 'EventTrigger' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggersCollection'.

Another one error that sometimes throwed instead:

> The value "EventTrigger" is not of type "ITrigger" and cannot be used in this generic collection. Parameter name: value

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016257/3998265 may be it would help