# Custom control like StackLayout with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, custom-controls, xamarin.forms

I just want to create a custom control with Xamarin.Forms. This custom control should take an array/list of views in the xaml (like the `Stacklayout`, for example).

My XAML Looks like this:

```
<controls:MyLayout>
    <ContentView BackgroundColor="Green">
        <Label Text="Test 1" />
    </ContentView>

    <ContentView BackgroundColor="Red">
        <Label Text="Test 1" />
    </ContentView>
</controls:MyLayout>
```

And the class for `MyLayout`:

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class MyLayout: ScrollView, IViewContainer<View>
{
     public IList<View> Children { get; set; }

    // And some more properties and methods ...
}
```

But when I compile this and run it on my Android phone, I get the following error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 29:8. Cannot assign
>   property "Children": type mismatch between "Xamarin.Forms.ContentView"
>   and "System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Xamarin.Forms.View]"

How can I solve this? What am I missing?

Comment: No, that't not the Problem. With 'ContentView' I got the same error: type mismatch between "Xamarin.Forms.ContentView" and "System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Xamarin.Forms.ContentView]"

Comment: You can refer the `Xamarin.Forms` source create your control, now that it's open source. You can find the code at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

This issue sounds like a known issue and is very old ...

To face that, I used the simple `IList` without generic type and it worked for `StackLayout`.

In your case I think you should first change your **base class** because `ScrollView` already has `[ContentProperty("Content")]` attribute, I think somewhere `ContentView` keep his priority.

The other approach would be to keep you **base class**, use `IList` without generic and anywhere you need it you say `Children as List<View>` or `if(Children is List<View> l)...`

**AND** don't forget to specify `<xxx:MyLayout.ContentView>` explicitly in your XAML as long as it is no longer the **ContentProperty**

Answer (score 0):

Your property Children must to have only get accessor. As I remember this was an issue a faced too. And also that list must be initialized.

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class MyLayout: ScrollView, IViewContainer<View>
{
     public IList<View> Children { get; } = new List<View>();

    // And some more properties and methods ...
}
```

I`d rather do like this

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Children))]
public class MyLayout: ScrollView, IViewContainer<View>
{
     private List<View> _children;
     public IList<View> Children => _children;

     public MyLayout()
     {
         _children = new List<View>();
     }
    // And some more properties and methods ...
}
```

Or even use ObservableCollection<> instead simple List<>. ObservableCollection can help you to observe when collection changes an it can help you when layout`s content children adds or removes from layout

Answer (score -1):

You need to put items into a container like:

```
    <ContentView BackgroundColor="Red">
        <Label Text="Test 1" />
    </ContentView>
</x:Array>
```

But I think its not a good approach. You can create a class for View collection like below and use it on your code, so you can observe if something added into it on runtime:

```
public class ViewCollection : ObservableCollection<View>
{

}


<controls:MyLayout>
    <local:ViewCollection Type="{x:Type View}">
        <ContentView BackgroundColor="Green">
            <Label Text="Test 1" />
        </ContentView>

        <ContentView BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Label Text="Test 1" />
        </ContentView>
    </local:ViewCollection>
</controls:MyLayout>
```

You also need to change `Children` property type to `ViewCollection`